# size of UITableViewCell.imageView changed with autolayout

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uiimageview, ios-autolayout

I am using UITableViewCell.imageView in uitableview to show images and with rounded corners of the imageview. WithFollowing Code

```
[cell2.imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
cell2.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell2.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell2.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell2.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell2.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
cell2.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(1/255.0) green:(146/255.0) blue:(219/255.0) alpha:1.0].CGColor;

[cell2.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ReviewArrayMain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"logo"]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Defaultlogo.png"] options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
            }else{
                cell2.imageView.image  = image;
                [cell2 layoutSubviews];
                cell2.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell2.imageView.frame.size.height/2;
            }
}];
```

i am getting perfect out put in one screen as below :

[image]

But in another Screen with the same code i am getting the below output :

[image]

I can't able to understand what is the issue ? and this is only happening with **iPad** Only . In iphone it's working perfectly.

The another thing i monitor is when i print the size of cell.imageview in both the screen i got the below log output:

***NSLog(@"Cell.imageview size W : %f H: %f",cell.imageView.frame.size.width,cell.imageView.frame.size.height);***

and it give me output on Screen A as below :
Cell.imageview size W **88.000000 H: 88.000000**

And on Screen B as below : 
Cell.imageview detailed size W : **44.000000 H: 44.000000**

Hope the issue is well understandable.

Comment: did u constraint the cell layout ?

Comment: may be you should corner more for ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, if you are setting corner radius in TableView's delegate method then please don't do this.
Instead of that Subclass the TableViewCell and set corner radius in its AwakeFromNib Method. This is more proper and efficient way.

Because CellForRowAtIndexPath Method called number of times cell reloaded. Where as We needs Rounded corner to be set once per Cell.

Ignore any Formatting please as I am on mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return (minimun height of your cell);
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //SenderChatCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SenderChatCell"];
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

this helped me ... hope it will help you as well